# Java Использование throw при создании метода

Tags: java, throw

Добрый день Опять прошу не сильно пинать и подсказать где делаю ошибку в обучении. Есть задача

Использование throw

•   Создать класс MoneyTransactionUtil

•   Создать приватный конструктор.

•   Создать статический метод для отправки денег с одного счета на другой: sendTo(номерКарты, номерКарты, сумма).

•   В методе следует обработать несколько возможных исключительных ситуаций:

•   Если номер карты отправителя и карты получателя совпадают, нужно выбросить RuntimeException. (throw new RuntimeException())

•   Если сумма является нулевой, отрицательной или больше 100_000, нужно выбросить RuntimeException. (throw new RuntimeException())

•   Добавить ключевое слово throws и RuntimeException к объявлению метода.

•   Если исключительных ситуаций нет, вывести на экран: «Сумма s, со счета n успешно переведена на счет m»

```
public class MoneyTransactionUtil {
private MoneyTransactionUtil() {
}

public static double sendTo (int idSender, int idReciver, double money)throws RuntimeException {
    try {
        if (money > 0 & idReciver != idSender)
            idReciver += money;
        if (idReciver == idSender)
            throw new RuntimeException("Отправитель равен получателю");
    } catch (RuntimeException r) {
        System.out.println(r.getMessage());
    }
    //return (int) idReciver;
    return money;
}
```

Я понимаю что где то косяк помогите разобраться что намудрил
Заранее спасибо кто отзовется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, этот код вам поможет:

```
    public class MoneyTransactionUtil {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                // Успешно
                sendTo(12345, 98765, 0.999);
                // Ошибка
                sendTo(12345, 12345, 55);
            } catch (RuntimeException r) {
                System.out.println(r.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static void sendTo(int idSender, int idReceiver, double money) {
            if (idReceiver == idSender)
                throw new RuntimeException("Отправитель равен получателю");
            if (money < 0 || money > 100_000)
                throw new RuntimeException("Некорректная сумма");
            System.out.println("Сумма " + money + ", со счета " + idSender +
                    " успешно переведена на счет " + idReceiver);
        }
    }
```

Здесь блок `try..catch` вынесен в тестовый метод `main`, добавлена проверка из задания, функция изменена на метод (*void*, а не возвращаемый тип). Так же у вас была ошибка в том, что вы пытались неправильно написать оператор **И** (надо **&&** вместо **&**), а так же прибавляли деньги к номеру счёта (что по задания вообще не нужно делать).

Так же хочу добавить, что `RuntimeException` является *непроверяемым исключением*, поэтому `throws` после функции писать не обязательно.

Comment: Скажите а можно ли с вами в телеге пообщаться?) я вам писал вчера @GradientAspen можете в телегу постучать мне?))